# how to generate regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

This is the format for which I want to generate regex `https://<any>.blob.core.windows.net/<any>?<any>` where any allowed any character(including special char also). I mean all where the other part is static.

Can you help to generate regex for above pattern?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will match *anything* in the places where you put `<any>`.

```
https:\/\/.*\.blob\.core\.windows\.net\/.*\?.*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^https:\/\/.+\.blob\.core\.windows\.net\/.+\?.+$/gm
```

`<any>` - any character (except for line terminators) between one and unlimited times. Can't be empty